# How to check a connection is established or not in appache airflow session

Tags: python, airflow

I want to establish a my sql connection with appache airflow

```
import json 
from airflow.settings import Session

from airflow.models.connection import Connection 

c = Connection(
     conn_id='some_conn',
     conn_type='mysql',
     description='connection description',
     host='myhost.com',
     login='myname',
     schema = 'myschema'
     password='mypassword',
     extra=json.dumps(dict(this_param='some val', that_param='other val*')),
 )
 session = Session()
 session.add(c)
 session.commit()
```

It throwing an error

(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed:

First time its working but the second time its not working ....

As per my understanding the connection i already added to airflow.session but how do I check that one this connection already added to tyhe session or not

I also want to know how to remove a connection from the session